# Trying AsyncStorage on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Currently, I am trying to storage a input value. However, it does not work. The code is able to launch without any error but the input values doesn't store to setTubeIT after I refresh the application.

```
                  <View style={styles.input}>
                    <TextInput placeholder="Inlet Temperature"
                        style={{flex:1}}
                        onChangeText={(value)=>setTubeIT(value)}
                        keyboardType={inputType}/>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:10}}>°C</Text>

_storedata :async () => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                'Inlet Temperature', 'setShellIT'
            );
        } catch (error) {
    
        }
    
    },
    
    _retrievedData : async () => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(
                'setShellIT');
                if (value!==null) {
                    console.log(value);
             }
    } catch (error) {

    }
}
```

Comment: what is this in _storedata : await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                'Inlet Temperature', 'setShellIT'
            ); !!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I am trying to debug and the system suggested ':' instead of '='. I am quite new to react native so might be doing some beginner mistakes!

Comment: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage#storing-data According to docs, you need to change the order of setItem params: `AsyncStorage.setItem('setShellIT', 'Inlet Temperature')`

Answer (score 0):

Please console.log(error) in your catch block and see if it returns an error